# Deleting or copying file: File to big for destination file system

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I've got a Windows 10 pc, with an internal (S:/) and external (I:/) hdd. Both are formatted to NTFS. I've made copies using bvckup 2 in the past.

Today I found a small error for copying new files to, and removing old ones from, the external hdd. Copying new files give me the error: File  is to big for the destination file system. Deleting a file on the external drive gives me the same error. Deleting was done by simply pressing the delete key while using windows explorer.

All files are shown to be 0 bytes on the external hdd.

I've tried to use Unlocker and I also tried to use the CMD 'convert' function, but those didn't work.

The files are between 500MB and 2.5GB in size, which aren't supposed to be an issue for a NTFS filesystem

**Edit the day after:** It seems that the issue has returned on the exFAT system too. I've formatted the drive yesterday and did a full backup with SyncToy. I guess this means that bvckup and synctoy are not the cause

Comment: It seems like my entire HDD crashed, Windows couldn't restore the drive and forced a complete format. Formatting the drive to NTFS didn't work, exFat was my only choice

Comment: Some clarification to the NTFS format that didn't work: Choosing NTFS and formatting using Windows Format window, gave the error: Formatting was not completed, try again. This same error was given when choosing the REFS system. exFat was the only option that could succeed the formatting, hence it was my only choice. The reason for this is still unclear to me.

Comment: So the exFAT system failed too, and I'm getting the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

The second time the issue occured (exFAT), I found a comment on the Microsoft Help forums about external HDD's. 
It seems that the External HDD Case couldn't handle a 3TB HDD. So when it reached it's limit of 2TB, it didn't know how to handle new files and folders.

**The issue has been resolved by buying a new HDD Case, which can handle bigger HDD's.**